# How can i make snake elongate when colliding with an object?

Tags: c++

I currently have a controllable snake head shape which responds to input and i also have some shapes that are drawn onto the game board. Could someone have a look at my code and help me out with any additions/amendments i can make to make my snake grow when it intersects with one of the spawned shapes?

All my project files are on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/u/Addsy

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could store snake's body parts in a linked list in your snake's class. Rendering would boil down to iterating over the list and rendering each part separately. As for moving, once you have a direction, you would move the head, and then move every body part in the list to the position of the one before it.
For example, the head moves first, the first part then moves to the previous position of the head, the second part to the position of the first part and so forth. To elongate the snake, on that move, you could create one more node at the end of the list, with the position of the tail before movement.

Comment: yeah that is exactly what i'm trying to do but as i'm limited with C++ code, i'm struggling with what to add to make this happen. Do you have any suggestions of what too add and where?

Comment: Have an std::list<Position> in your snake's class.The first element ( the head of the list ) would be the position of the head of your snake, every following element would be the body.Next, you would have to edit the your move function to instead move every element in the list, not just the head. I have only glanced over your code, but I assume you have some function to check whether the snake can advance in the chosen direction? If so, you could have a bool variable in the class, that would be set to true if your snake will collide with a shape on the next turn, and grow it in move.